# Android - Transition animations in nested PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, user-preferences

I am developing a settings screen using nested PreferenceScreen classes.
As of now, when I click on a PreferenceScreen, it moves to the nested screen without any animation.

Can anybody tell me how can I make this transition into a nested PreferenceScreen and out back to top level PreferenceScreen with animation?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so clear, but check this out.
https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere

Comment: I am using android PreferenceScreen class.